# Powerpoint automation using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

I am getting error message with the following code:

```
Dim objPPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim objPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

'Opening blank presentation
Set objPPT = WScript.CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.visible = 1
Set objPres = objPPT.presentations.Add
objPres.Slides.Add (1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank)
```

This Script stops execution prompting error message as `Line 1 Char 12 Expected End of statement`

I am new to vbscript, Please help if I am making some mistake.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433059/writing-custom-code-for-powerpoint#

Any idea?

Comment: try www.pptxbuilder.com, it automate excel data to charts in powerpoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use [vbscript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), you must know syntax of vbscript. Below is example code to Add a Slide to PPT (PPT Template used here)

```
' Add a Slide to a Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation
 Const ppLayoutText = 2

 Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
 objPPT.Visible = True

 Set objPresentation = objPPT.Presentations.Add

 objPresentation.ApplyTemplate _
 ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\1033\ProjectStatusReport.potx")

 Set objSlide = objPresentation.Slides.Add _
 (1, ppLayoutText)
```